# Is it true that database management systems typically bypass file systems..?

Tags: mysql, database, filesystems, operating-system, storage

Is my general understanding that a typical database management systems bypass file system correct? I understand that they manage their own space on disk and they write actual data and index systems like B tree directly into disk blocks bypassing any intermediate help from file system.

This assumes that root would provide the database user permission to directly read and write from disk blocks. In Linux, this is still easier as disk can be treated as a file.

Any pointer to real case studies will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most rely on the underlying file system for [WAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) etc: basically they outsource it to the OS.

Some DBMS support (Oracle, MySQL) "raw" partitions, but it isn't typical. Too much hassle  ([see this chat about Postgres](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Can-postgresql-store-its-data-on-raw-device-now-td1920054.html)) because you still need WAL etc on your raw partition.

Answer (score 3):

DBMSs do not bypass filesystem. If this was the case, the table names would not be case-insensitive under Windows and case-sensitive under Linux (in MySQL). What they do is to allocate large space on the file system (by the way, the data is still visible as a file / set of files in the underlying operating system) and manage internal data structure. This lower the fragmentation and the overall overhead. In a similar way cache systems works - Varnish allocates entire memory it needs with a single call to operating system, then maitains internal data structure.

Comment: "table names would not be case-insensitive under Windows"  This has nothing to do with the filesystem since it is up to the DBMS how it identifies tables.  For example, SQL Server supports both case sensitive and insensitive collations on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely, mysql asks for data directory and stores the data in a specific [file format](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats) where it tries to optimize the reads,writes from a file and also stores indexes there.

More over it can also differ from one storage engine to another.
[Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching) uses memory mapped files for disk IO
Looking forward for more discussion here.

Comment: but articles like at http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525 make me think that objects in database are not stored through file system hence leading the scope of such debates like blobs vs file systems. where am I going wrong?

Comment: debates of blobs vs file systems discuss if the benefits of going through the database layer bring enough benefit as opposed to bypassing the database layer (which is completely different from database bypassing the file system layer)