# How Does MySQL/Similar DBs Access the Disk?

Tags: java, c++, mysql, disk, hard-drive

I recall from my introductory database course that we mostly talked about data on the disk block level, and discussed things like rearranging related data so they reside on contiguous blocks. However, I've only ever accessed the disk using high-level abstractions such as files and streams while using C++/Java. On what level, and with what interface, do database systems access the disk in code? Is this done differently in C++ vs Java (or for example, MySQL's InnoDB vs Cassandra)? I've tried looking through the MySQL source for the related code but quickly became lost...

Comment: Hi, I think this question is pretty much a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760228/is-it-true-that-database-management-systems-typically-bypass-file-systems). Hope it helps.